# How do I regenerate /etc/resolv.conf from /etc/systemd/resolved.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, dns, libvirt, vagrant

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here:

https://www.itwonderlab.com/en/ansible-kubernetes-vagrant-tutorial/

using Debian 10 as the vagrant host, and as Debian no longer supports Virtual Box, I'm using libvirt.

Thus, I had to change the image to `generic/ubuntu2010`.

Unfortunately it looks like DNS is not working inside the vm.

```
curl google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

As soon as I change the nameserver line to an ip of a well known nameserver, it works fine.

So should be as simple as just editing `/etc/resolv.conf`, but I see also:

`This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.`

So after looking through the docs, it looks like I need to edit:

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

After opening that file, I can see some nameserver ips in there already that don't match `/etc/resolv.conf`.

So how exactly do I regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf` from `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` on Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: If `systemd-resolved` is in use, just changing `/etc/resolv.conf` away from `127.0.0.53` is not enough: you must also replace `resolve` with `dns` on the `hosts:` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. That keyword causes most applications to use `libnss_resolve.so` instead of the classic `libnss_dns.so` for DNS-based hostname resolution. The `nameserver 127.0.0.53` is just for those special programs that will make their own DNS queries without using the glibc name service switch functionality.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl is-active systemd-resolved` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: `systemctl is-active systemd-resolved`: `active` and `/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

Comment: Could it be you are trying to solve this in the worng end?  If you have problems with dns resolution, the first thing to check is your libvirt setup.  And if you are following a tutorial designed for virtualbox, I suggest installing virtualbox, even if debian-maintainers don't like it.  There's plenty of howtos for that.

Comment: The problem isn't libvirt. Remember, as soon as I change `/etc/resolv.conf` in the vm, DNS works fine, immediately. The problem is trying to figure out how systemd or resolved generates  `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: For example, if I create a new Vagrantfile with `generic/debian10`, DNS works fine out of the box. But unfortunately the `generic/debian10` image will not work for that tutorial, it looks like Ubuntu must be used. So the goal here is to get DNS working with `generic/ubuntu2010`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was DNSSEC.

Adding this:

```
- name: Fix DNS 
  lineinfile: 
    path: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
    regex: '^DNSSEC='
    line: 'DNSSEC=no'

- name: Restart resolved
  service:
    name: systemd-resolved
    state: restarted
```

to `roles/common/add_packages/tasks/main.yml` fixed the issue.

I'm not sure how `generic/ubuntu2010` is useful to anyone with broken DNS.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am facing the same issue, but I do not understand the solution. I do not have any `main.yml` file on the system.

Comment: I believe he's talking about his ansible configuration. Ansible is for keeping a system up to date WRT packages and configurations. So he's changing his Ansible configuration to fis the problem. Specifically he's setting the line DNSSEC in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to "no" and restarting systemd-resolved service to pick up the change.

Problem is with mine, DNSSEC is commented out and it seems the default value was no anyway.